# Chrome Extension development error : Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ejs

I am new to writing chrome extension. 
I am trying to open an ejs template inside my injected content script, but I get **below error** in content_script.js when I do new EJS({})

"Denying load of chrome-extension://eadcfllkpeiejpedposonemnmmpnggie/content.html.ejs. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension."

*Note:* I have added the resource in the web_accessible_resource

Manifest.json

```
    {
    "name"              : "test",
    "description"       : " app",
    "version"           : "1.0",
    "manifest_version"  : 2,
    "browser_action"    :{
                            "default_icon"   : "images/icon.png"
                        },
    "permissions"       : ["tabs","notifications","contextMenus","background","http://*/*","https://*/*","<all_urls>"],
    "options_page"      : "views/options.html",
    "icons"             : {"16"         : "images/icon-16.png"//Icon context menu},
    "background"        : {
                            "page"          : "views/background.html",
                            "js"            : ["scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"]
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": ["views/content.html.ejs"]
}
```

**Background.js**

```
    'use strict';

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(tab){
    chrome.contextMenus.create({
        title : "Add as reminder",
        id    : "rappelSelection",
        contexts: ["selection"],
        onclick: function(info,tab){addContent(info,tab)}
    })
});


function addContent(info, tab){
    var details = {};
    details.text = info.selectionText;
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file : "scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"
    });

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file : "scripts/ejs_min.js"
    });

    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        file : "scripts/content_script.js"
    });

    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab){
        chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {details: details}, function(response){
            console.log(response);
        });
    });
}
```

**content_script**

```
chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function newContent(request, sender, sendResponse){
        var template_path = chrome.extension.getURL('content.html.ejs');
        var data = {content: request.details.text };
        var template = new EJS({url:template_path}).render(data);
        $("body").append(template);
        sendResponse({contentText: "goodbye"}); 
    });
```

Comment: Your manifest lists `"views/content.html.ejs"` while your script tries to load `chrome.extension.getURL('content.html.ejs')` without the `views` part. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: That said, you should upgrade APIs you're using. `onRequest`/`sendRequest` are deprecated since a long time - use `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` and `chrome.runtime.onMessage`.

Comment: Thanks will update and check

Answer (score 0):

getURL method needs path of the File from the root of the not just the filename 
Changing

```
var template_path = chrome.extension.getURL('content.html.ejs');
```

to

```
 var template_path = chrome.extension.getURL('views/content.html.ejs');
```

Fixed the issue.
Thanks @Xan needed an another pair of eyes to see that :)